# Where to place Google Webmaster verification file

Tags: ftp

I'm in the process of uploading the Google Webmaster verification file via FTP, and I just want to check with you guys that I'm putting it in the right place.

Below is a screenshot of what I can see. Do I upload it here or do I need to go into one of the folders and upload it there?

[image]

Thanks as always! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the file in the root of you installation. From your print screen the file needs to be placed in **/public_html/**

You can confirm by visiting your website by pointing a web browser to www.yoursite.com/google-file.html